How to reboot back into Windows on a PC with another OS set as the default in the EFI?
Rationale
I primarily use Fedora 40's KDE Spin, but secondarily use Windows 11 Pro. To apply updates to Windows, I must reboot the PC. However, because Fedora is set as the default OS in the EFI's GUI, this can cause the PC to boot into Fedora, thereby unapplying the Windows update (in practice). To remediate this, I instruct Windows to boot into the UEFI's bootloader GUI so that I can manually choose the Windows Boot Loader on the next boot.
However, this is tedious. I would much prefer to merely instruct Windows to modify the boot order for the next boot to such that Windows shall automatically boot back into Windows again.
Attempts
To accomplish this, I managed to locate a comment on Reddit, which instructs me to invoke the undermentioned. I have modified it due to subsequent communications with the parent comment's author:
#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

sudo BCDEdit /BootSequence '{current}' && ` <# [Yes, `sudo` exists for Windows.](https://github.com/microsoft/sudo/blob/d67aaec73801d5d325bc5733a671bf04ce95888f/README.md#-sudo-for-windows) #>
shutdown /r /t 0                             # [I'd like to use `Restart-Computer`.](https://superuser.com/revisions/1855231/2)

However, although the commands execute successfully:

PS C:\Users\rokej> sudo BCDEdit /BootSequence '{current}'
The operation completed successfully.


...I reboot into Fedora regardless.
I expect it to function due to:

The output of bcdedit /enum returning {current} for my current boot entry, and
$? responding $True after invocation

...but alas.
Linux Counterpart (Example)
This might be useful - I use the undermentioned command to invoke Windows from Fedora:

#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh

# Requirements
# ------------

    #```PS1
    #Requires -PSEdition Core
    #Requires -Version 7.4.5
    #```

    Set-StrictMode -Version 'Latest'
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Script
# ------

    sudo efibootmgr --bootnext $(efibootmgr | grep -e 'Windows' | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | cut -d't' -f2 | sed s/.$//) && Restart-Computer


I would expect that this can be adapted to reinitialize Fedora into itself should I have Windows set as the default, so I'll be surprised if its bcdedit counterpart cannot.

It's much simpler to just temporarily change the boot order to Windows, install the updates with all the reboot then change it back to GRUB.

@ChanganAuto, not if I can have a script do so for me.

No, it's 10x the work for a 'maybe' result, at best.

@ChanganAuto, I'm going to be performing this action multiple times per week for the rest of my many decades of life. I really don't understand your reticence.

Just to confirm, since you are planning to use sudo, you are running Windows 11 24H2 on your system? I ask because Windows 11 24H2 has NOT actually been released. Does the value of {current} match the GUID for your Fedora EFI entry or does it match the Windows entry?

Yeah, I'm using 24H2 via the Release Candidate branch (as of +2024-09-11T19:12+01:00). To my knowledge, {current} can only match the Windows entry, because bcdedit isn't available on any OS except Windows (its Linux counterpart, as aforementioned, is efibootmgr). Unfortunately, efibootmgr doesn't utilize (G/U)UIDs, so I can't compare across OSes.

RokeJulianLockhart: In your question, you state "cause the PC to boot into Windows". Do you "mean cause the PC to boot into Fedora"?

It might be helpful to read this question.

@DavidAnderson, yes. I meant to put "Fedora" there. Remediated in an improvement to your suggestion. Thank you.

@DavidAnderson, I did see that question a long time ago, and appeared to have upvoted https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57862653/2, which continues to look like an answer - that is, if I hadn't tried it and watched it fail to work, per this question. Have I missed something?

You can achieve this by always booting into GRUB, acknowledging Windows Boot Manager's unreliability for these kinds of use-cases.
In Linux, you can set up GRUB to always boot the most recently selected option. Set the following in the file /etc/default/grub:
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

Then run the following to commit the changes:
sudo update-grub

Now, you will boot by default into Linux, and can select Windows in the GRUB menu to then boot-loop through updates automatically. When done updating, you'd restart and select Linux again.
You can also select Windows for one-off use by entering these commands into a terminal on Linux:
sudo grub-reboot n
sudo reboot

Replace n with the index of Windows in the boot menu (the first option is zero). Then after finishing with Windows, a restart will automatically boot into Linux.
